# Jquery animate with window scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a javascript effect on a div like a garage door.
Basically I'd have a div on the back and another div on front which would shrink from bottom to top base on window scroll.

I have a JSFiddle that does what I want only, but I have to give the div size myself, I want the size to be dynamic based on the scroll of the window size.

Here the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/onlymushu/gTsHf/
And the code:

```
HTML
<div id="container">
    <div id="contents">
        1. This is going to be very big line.
        2. This is going to be very big line.
        3. This is going to be very big line.
        4. This is going to be very big line.
        5. This is going to be very big line.
        6. This is going to be very big line.
        7. This is going to be very big line.
        8. This is going to be very big line.
    </div>
</div>
<button id="up">up</div>
    <button id="down">down</div>

CSS
body{
    height: 1500px;
}
#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: red;
    Position:relative;border:1px #000 solid;
}
#contents{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: white;
    overflow:hidden;
}

JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up").click(function(){
        $("#contents").animate({height:"0px"},500);
    });
    $("#down").click(function(){
        $("#contents").animate({height:"300px"},500);
    });
});
```

Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set

```
position:fixed;
```

on the #container it will sit still while the scroll bar moves.
Then in your document ready function, make sure there is plenty of room for scrolling:

```
var minHeight = $("#container").height() * 4;
if ($("body").height() < minHeight) $("body").height(minHeight);
```

And in the scroll function, use the percent scrolled:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var newSize = $("#container").height() * (1 - $(window).scrollTop() /  ($(document).height() - $(window).height()));
    $("#contents").css('height',newSize);
});
```

I would recommend not animating in the scroll function because it will be called frequently.

I took the liberty of updating [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTsHf/3/)

Comment: I look at it on my phone its seems fairely simple. Thanks a lot, I'll check it on my computer tonight. I'll keep in mind your recommendations.